# App is STILL not updating database when string contains spaces

Tags: mysql, ios, database, spaces

Slowly but surely I think I'm going mad. After getting the solution to my problem and the app now also accepting spaces, it still won't add the data that contains spaces to my mysql database. Here is the code:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bbc.com/phpFile.php?number=%@&name=%@&lastname=%@", number, firstName, lastName];
NSString *webStringURl = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
NSLog(@"%@", webStringURl);
```

NSLog even tells me that it does exactly what I tell him to:

```
ProjectX[4003:15203] http://www.bbc.com/phpFile.php?number=11166&name=Yong%20Wang%20Ding&lastname=Blamblam
```

It works everytime when the variables do not contain spaces. When I open the php file in my browser and enter the variables by hand (with spaces) it adds them to my database. I have no clue why it refuses to work when doing exactly(?) the same thing with my app.

Comment: Is it odd that I have an entire Xcode project set aside for editing formatting on StackOverflow posts? Anyways, please remember to check your posts over for code formatting mistakes before posting next time. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using webStringURl (sic) anywhere other than in the final NSLog statement. Are you sure you didn't mean to write:

```
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURl];
```

...for the third line?

At the moment, you're calling dataWithContentsOfURL on your unescaped version of the URL (which may still contain spaces).

Comment: Thanks, it is really frustrating when those kinda obvious things escape you totally. Good thing there is stackoverflow :)